# The definition of independence depends on the target spaces of the random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X,Y: \Omega \to M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be two random vectors that takes values in a topological subspace $M \subset  \mathbb{R}^d$. Consider the two conditions:

(1) $X, Y: \Omega \to M $ are independent.

(2) $X,Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ are independent.

My question is: are these two conditions equivalent?

It seems (1) implies (2): let $\iota: M \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be the embedding. The, $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d, P[(\iota \circ X)^{-1}(E) \cap (\iota \circ Y)^{-1}(E)]= P[X^{-1}\iota^{-1}(E) \cap Y^{-1}\iota^{-1}(E)]= P[X^{-1}(E \cap M) \cap Y^{-1}(E \cap M)]= P[X^{-1}(E \cap M)]P[Y^{-1}(E \cap M)]= P[(\iota \circ X)^{-1}(E)] P[(\iota \circ Y)^{-1}(E)]$.

But I'm not sure about the other direction: does (2) imply (1) nevessarily? Can you give a step by step proof? I'm gettign stuck at the point where you've to consider the relative open sets .Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. (A small note: we should assume $M$ is a Borel set.) I will provide a proof of both directions since your proof of $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ only shows $P(\{X\in E\}\cap\{ Y\in E\})=P(X\in E)P(Y\in E)$ for all Borel $E\subset\mathbb R^d$, which is not quite sufficient. First, some notation:

- We will write $\{X\in E\}$ instead of $X^{-1}(E)$. This is just to better illustrate what our objects actually mean.
- We will not bother with the embedding function $\iota:M\to \mathbb R^d$, since $E\subset M$ implies $E\subset\mathbb R^d$.

Let's prove $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$. Specifically, we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent as random variables taking values in $M$, and we must prove that if $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R^d$,
$$P\Big(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\}\Big)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B).$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ take values in $M$, one has $\{X\in A\}=\{X\in M\cap A\}$ and $\{Y\in B\}=\{Y\in M\cap B\}$. Since $M\cap A$ and $M\cap B$ are subsets of $M$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent when viewed as $M$-valued random variables,
$$P\Big(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\}\Big) = P\Big(\{X\in M\cap A\} \cap \{Y\in M\cap B\}\Big) = P(X\in M\cap A)P(Y\in M\cap B) = P(X\in A)P(X\in B).$$

This shows $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$. Now assume $(2)$, and we will prove $(1)$, that is, we will show that for any Borel sets $A,B\subseteq M$,
$$P\Big(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\}\Big) = P(X\in A)P(Y\in B).$$
But this is immediate: since $A,B\subseteq M\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, this follows from the independence of $X$ and $Y$ when viewed as $\mathbb R^d$-valued random variables. Thus, the two notions are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer, and proving that the notion of independence carries over to Borel measurable subsets of the bigger set (topological space). Yes I see that the fact $M$ is a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is necessary in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The question whether $X:\Omega\to M$ and $Y\to M$ are independent
is determined by the behaviour of $P$ on sets of the form $A\cap B$
where $A\in\sigma\left(X\right)$ and $B\in\sigma\left(Y\right)$.

The question whether $\iota\circ X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\iota\circ Y\to\mathbb{R}$
are independent is determined by the behaviour of $P$ on sets of
the form $A\cap B$ where $A\in\sigma\left(\iota\circ X\right)$ and
$B\in\sigma\left(\iota\circ X\right)$.

So to show equivalence it is enough to prove that $\sigma\left(X\right)=\sigma\left(\iota\circ X\right)$
and $\sigma\left(Y\right)=\sigma\left(\iota\circ Y\right)$

If the range of $X$ is a subset of $M\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)$
then $\left(\iota\circ X\right)^{-1}\left(S\right)=X^{-1}\left(M\cap S\right)=X^{-1}\left(S\right)$
for every $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and consequently:

$$\sigma\left(\iota\circ X\right)=\left\{ \left(\iota\circ X\right)^{-1}\left(B\right)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)\right\} =\left\{ X^{-1}\left(B\right)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)\right\} =$$$$\left\{ X^{-1}\left(B\right)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right),B\subseteq M\right\} =\sigma\left(X\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer - another way of looking at it!

Comment: You are very welcome.